# Convergence of a product of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have two sequences $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ such that $$ \sum_{k\geq0} a^2_k <\infty \text{ 
 and } \sum_{k\geq0}b^2_{k} < \infty $$

Can we say that $$\sum_{k\geq0} a_kb_k < \infty$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300835/show-if-sum-limits-k-1-infty-a-k2-sum-limits-k-1-infty-b-k2-co?rq=1

Comment: [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality)

Comment: $\sum_{k\ge 0} a_kb_k < \infty$ is not really what you want to say. Better to ask if $ \sum_{k\geq0} a_kb_k$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|2ab|\leq a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

By the C-S inequality, 
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}|a_kb_k|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}a_k^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}b_k^2}
$$
both of which are finite.